# Django's StaticLiveServerTestCase test pass alone but fail when grouped

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm using `Selenium` along with `StaticLiveServerTestCase` to test a Django app.

The test is as follow:

```
class e2eTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(IntegrationTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.data = load_data()
        cls.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("path_to_phantomjs")
        cls.common = common(cls.driver, cls.live_server_url + settings.STATIC_URL + 'index.html')

    def setUp(self):
        for data in self.data:
            data.refresh_from_db()

    def test_login_1(self):
        self.common.login('admin')

    def test_login_2(self):
        self.common.login('admin')
```

`load_data()` is used to populate test database (using apps `models`).

If I run:

1- `python manage.py test login.tests`: the tests start with `test_login_1`. `test_login_1` succeed and `test_login_2` fail.

2- `python manage.py test login.tests --reverse`: the tests start with `test_login_2`. `test_login_2` succeed and `test_login_1` fail.

I believe it have something to do with data begin erased after each test.
P.S. When using same approach using `django.test.TestCase` & `setUpTestData` and Django's test client it works ( sending the data to the login api directly ).

Can I have something like `setUpTestData` from `django.test.TestCase` ?

**EDIT 1**

@luke_aus: `load_data()` contain methods to populate the test database:

```
from my_app import User, priceModel
user = User(username='test').set_password('test')
user.save()
priceModel = priceModel(name='test')
priceModel.save()
....
```

@knbk: I'm using Django 1.9. The test still fail after passing `--parallel=1`.

Thanks you both for your feedback!

Comment: what's in load_data()?

Comment: If you're using Django 1.9+: does it still fail if you pass `--parallel=1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by `load_data()`. The database will get populated in the first call to `load_data()` from `setUpClass`, and the first test will passes. For the second test, the database data will be cleared and not refreshed.

Changing `load_data()` method to load fixtures solved the problem.